# Show that the following set is countable

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the following set is countable:  $\{f ∶ \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} ∶ \forall$ m, n $\in \mathbb{N}$ m $ \leq$ n $\implies$ $f (n) \leq f (m)\}.$

Comment: Welcome to MSE, Marisol! What have you tried? Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I would like to find a bijection between the set and a subset of the natural ones but I have no ideas

Comment: The range of any such function must be finite. Therefore, each function with $|\text{ran}f| = n$ can be mapped to a $2n$-tuple $\langle a_1,\dots, a_{2n}\rangle$ such that for $1\leq k\leq n$ $a_k$ denotes the $k^{\text{th}}$ largest element of the range and $a_{n+k}$ is the smallest natural number $m$ for which $f(m) = a_{k}$. For instance, $\langle 23, 4, 0, 5\rangle$ denotes the function $\langle 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 4, 4, 4,\dots\rangle$. Then use the fact that the collection of finite tuples of natural numbers is countable.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Let $F$ be the set of functions in question. Don’t try to find an injection from $F$ to $\Bbb N$ directly; use various facts about countable sets that you already know after you prove the following results.

- Show that every $f\in F$ is eventually constant, meaning that there are an $n_f\in\Bbb N$ and a $k_f\in\Bbb N$ such that $f(n)=k_f$ for all $n\ge n_f$.
- Show that for each $\langle\ell,k,n\rangle$ there are only finitely many $f\in F$ such that $f(0)=\ell$, $k_f=k$, and $n_f=n$. (My $\Bbb N$ includes $0$; if yours starts with $1$, replace $f(0)$ with $f(1)$.)